# MultiModelExtensionBase for multi-model viewing in autodesk forge

Tags: javascript, angularjs, autodesk-forge, viewer

Im trying to use autodesk forge viewer for viewing multiple models in the same viewer. As to start, i have followed these blog posts for refrences:

- https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/preparing-your-viewing-application-multi-model-workflows
- https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/preparing-your-viewing-application-multi-model-workflows-part-2-model-loader

But while loading the Extension "Viewing.Extension.MultiModelExtensionBase"
is not found. Is there any documentation regarding this extension or anything else related to it?

Comment: This extension is part of a bigger project: https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-rcdb.nodejs and has dependencies to components implemented in this project. It is not part of the Viewer API itself and you will not be able to reuse it directly in your own project. I suggest you simply take a look at the code and use the part that you need, otherwise deploy the forge-rcdb demo on your side. If you want to test the live demo use the links from those articles.

Comment: @Philippe i want to use multiple model in a viewer, do i need some kind of extra extension to do that?

Comment: No, you just need to read the articles: https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2016/02/model-aggregation-with-view-data-api-exposed.html

Comment: Adding to Philippe's answer - 

here is a minimal demo with source and blog post:
... demo: https://wallabyway.github.io/viewer-multimodel-search/
...
src: https://github.com/wallabyway/viewer-multimodel-search
...
blog: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/multimodel-search-support-forge-viewer-v40